# Xcopy not creating source folder on target drive

Tags: xcopy

I'd like to copy this folder:

> c:\temp\test

to

> e:\backup

with

> xcopy c:\temp\test e:\backup\ /S

and I expect to get everything in this folder:

> e:\backup\test

Not so. The files from TEST folder are now in BACKUP folder and not in the subfolder TEST.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Source [XCOPY](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)

> **Syntax**
>
> XCOPY source [destination] [options]
>
> **Key**
>
> - source      : Pathname for the file(s) to be copied.
> - destination : Pathname for the new file(s).
> - [options] can be any combination of the following:
>
> ...
>
> **Copy Options**
>
> - /I           If in doubt always assume the destination is a folder
>                 e.g. when the destination does not exist. ...
>
> **Examples**:
>
> To copy a file:
>
> XCOPY C:\utils\MyFile D:\Backup\CopyFile
>
> To copy a folder:
>
> XCOPY C:\utils D:\Backup\utils /i
>
> To copy a folder including all subfolders.
>
> XCOPY C:\utils* D:\Backup\utils /s /i
>
> The /i defines the destination as a folder.

Given the above, please try the following:

```
xcopy c:\temp\test\* e:\backup\test /s /i
```

Comment: This works, I know.
But how to make XCOPY create a destination folder with the same name as source folder without me explicitly stating so?

Comment: You can't as xcopy was not written to work that way :/

Comment: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here.